# SQL statement error on continuation to next line in vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, winforms

Here's the SQL statement which I want to continue to the next line but its showing error in the value clause, I actually want to break the statement into multiple lines

```
sqlstr = "insert into       pos_invoice_hdr(invoice_no, loc_code, invoce_type, invoice_date, cust_code, gross_amt, disc_percent, net_amt, doctor_code, loose_qty, pkt_qty, remarks, ccy, card_no, card_type, invoice_by) _"
    "values("@invoice_no, @loc_code, @invoice_type, @invoice_Date, @cust_code, @gross_amt, @disc_percent, @net")"
```

Comment: try adding a '&' to the start of the second line. different VS versions allow different ways to do basic line continuation, but for strings that should work

Comment: probably you dont need extra-quotes inside brackets in the second line

Comment: @plutonix:its still not working,giving syntax error

Comment: @angelo it shows blue wavy lines... i actually want to break the statement into multiple lines by adding a continuation character

Comment: what langguage are you using?

Comment: @angelo i am using vb.net,framework 4.0

Answer (score 0):

Your statement has **less input params** than the table is expecting.

16 fields...

```
(invoice_no, 
 loc_code, 
 invoce_type, 
 invoice_date, 
 cust_code, 
 gross_amt, 
 disc_percent, 
 net_amt, 
 doctor_code, 
 loose_qty, 
 pkt_qty, 
 remarks, 
 ccy, 
 card_no, 
 card_type, 
 invoice_by) _"
values
```

8 values...

```
("@invoice_no, 
@loc_code, 
@invoice_type,
@invoice_Date, 
@cust_code, 
@gross_amt,
@disc_percent,
@net")"
```

You either need to remove the following fields..

```
doctor_code, 
     loose_qty, 
     pkt_qty, 
     remarks, 
     ccy, 
     card_no, 
     card_type, 
     invoice_by
```

or add more values.

Comment: i have removed the extra fields but i want to know how to continue to the next line

Comment: it shows blue wavy lines... i actually want to break the statement into multiple lines by adding a continuation character

Answer (score 0):

have you tried something like this?

```
sqlstr = "insert into pos_invoice_hdr(invoice_no, loc_code, invoce_type,   invoice_date, cust_code, gross_amt, disc_percent, net_amt, doctor_code, loose_qty, pkt_qty,  remarks, ccy, card_no, card_type, invoice_by)" & _
     "values(@invoice_no, @loc_code, @invoice_type, @invoice_Date, @cust_code,   @gross_amt, @disc_percent, @net)"
```

something like

```
 Dim str as string 
       str = "first string" & _
           "second string"
```